# UDP+RUDP or UDP+TCP?

Tags: networking, protocol

I made a library that enables client-server communication using both TCP and UDP protocols. When game developers on the #gamedev IRC channel (Freenode) knew that, they totally refused the idea. They recommended RUDP instead of TCP. Should I remove the TCP communication and use RUDP instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RUDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol) is a very exotic non-standard transport-layer protocol which is not supported on any mainstream networking hardware or operating system.

However, there are libraries which implement protocols on top of UDP which have additional TCP-like reliability features but still fulfill the requirements of real-time games. One such library is [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org/). The Unity engine also does something similar when requested.

But TCP should not be totally dismissed for game development. Sure, it is unsuitable for real-time games where latency matters, but it is still a very useful protocol for turn-based games.

Comment: Why RUDP and not TCP?? Both TCP and RUDP have similar speed.

Comment: @None As I said, the RUDP protocol is not supported anywhere. The only transport-layer protocols you can assume to be available on a common network are TCP and UDP.